# How to set a Scala callback function as a parameter in Java?

Tags: java, scala, java-8

I'm new to Scala and having to work with a library written in Java from Scala. Here's the desired flow:

1. Call a Java method, `public void myMethod(?)` from Scala
2. `myMethod` could potentially be long running, so in the `?` bit I want to have a callback mechanism
3. `myMethod` completes, in this case I don't really care about the result so the return value doesn't matter.

I have found plenty of examples of calling Scala from Java and vice versa but not as a referenced parameter in a Java function. I imagine this is something like setting an interface parameter in Java, but my attempts have failed:

```
// java
public interface Callback {
  void callback(double d);
}

public void myMethod(Callback callback) {
   // do some stuff
   callback.callback(123D);
   // do more stuff
}

// scala
x.myMethod((x: Double) => {})
```

Comment: What error are you getting? What version of Scala are you using? Your code should work out-of-the-box in Scala 2.12+ due to support for [lambda syntax for SAM types](https://www.scala-lang.org/news/2.12.0/#lambda-syntax-for-sam-types).

Comment: If the issue is that the call to myMethod blocks the rest of your execution, you could look into Futures in Scala.

Comment: Argh, @MarioGalic you're right - my blind effort was indeed working but the IDE was picking up the wrong version of scala on the machine and there was a compilation error. Thanks!